# Searching for key in PHP Multidimensional array and get its value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array called `$array` which contains following data

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
        [month_count] => January
        [atmos_gb] => 4
        [atmos_h3] => 16
        [waterh3_river] => 8
        [waterh3_pond] => 1
    )
    [1] => Array(
        [month_count] => February
        [atmos_gb] => 4
        [atmos_h3] => 8
        [waterh3_river] => 5
        [waterh3_pond] => 0
    )
    [2] => Array(
        [month_count] => March
        [atmos_gb] => 5
        [atmos_h3] => 7
        [waterh3_river] => 5
        [waterh3_pond] => 0
    )
    [3] => Array(
        [month_count] => April
        [atmos_gb] => 0
        [atmos_h3] => 2
        [waterh3_river] => 2
        [waterh3_pond] => 0
    )
)
```

I want to get the value of of a particular cell, say `[2][atmos_gb]`.

How can I get this value?

Comment: What's preventing you from doing `echo $array[2][atmos_gb];`?

Comment: If you want to get the `atmos_gb` value for each column, you can take advantage of PHP's [array_column()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) function: `$atmos_gb_values = array_column($myArray, 'atmos_gb');`... if you're running PHP>=5.5.0

Comment: If you want to be really clever and just get the value of `[2][atmos_gb]`, you can do: `$atmos_gb_2 = array_column($myArray, 'atmos_gb')[2];`